# Помогите решить задачу на python

Tags: python

сообщество.
Изучаю python, застрял на такой задаче

1) Напишите программу, которая будет принимать числа от пользователя и суммировать их, пока он не напишет слово «sum».
2) Когда пользователь напишет слово «sum», должна быть выведена сумма всех чисел и начат процесс заново.
3) Если пользователь напишет «exit» или «quit», программа должна быть завершена.

Помогите решить, пожалуйста

Comment: здесь не принято решать задачки за других. Конкретизируй что именно из этих пунктов не получается. Покажи код, который написал сам.

Comment: так я не понимаю, как множественно данные вводить. До массивов еще не дошел,а задача уже такая =( Учил другие языки, но python отличается.  Вот знаю,как ввести данные с клавиатуры при помощи input(), но как вводить множественно - не догоняю.  Понятно, что потом можно через if проверить, введено ли sum и если да, то суммировать все введенные числа и записывать результат,выводить.  То же самое,в принципе, можно с quit или exit. выведена сумма всех чисел - это понятно,  и начат процесс заново - непонятно, как зациклить, чтобы программа исполнялась не единоразово,а много раз

Comment: подсказка - while True: x = int(input()), вроде не сложно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = True
summa = 0
while i:
    prompt = input("> ")
    if prompt == "sum":
        print(summa)
        summa=0
    elif prompt == "quit" or prompt == "exit":
        print("Bye!")
        break
    else:
        try:
            summa+=int(prompt)
        except:
            print("Damn you!Wrong command!")
```

Comment: Если мой ответ был полезен ,примите его нажав галочку около него.

Comment: можно сразу `while True`, сумма не обнуляется после вывода

Comment: Спасибо. Суть понятна. Не совсем ясно в чем именно косяк, ведь если в первый раз ввести несколько числе, а потом sum при таком раскладе, то выдаст ошибку о том,что команда неверная. Если сразу же ввести еще раз, то покажет сумму

Comment: Может после сум пробел?

Comment: Вроде сразу жму Enter

Answer (score 0):

```
summa = 0
while True:
    prompt = input("> ")
    if prompt == "sum":
        print(summa)
        summa=0
        continue #!!!!
    elif prompt == "quit" or prompt == "exit":
        print("Bye!")
        break

    summa += int(prompt)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]